# Reges to catch different types of url having parameters

Tags: regex

I have a regex that i need to be able to catch all full url that are found in a string. The url may have parameters and it still need to catch it.

I have worked on it here: https://regex101.com/r/cKLZuo/2

but the last one is not working fine. I want to be able to catch `\"` but not `"` as the last character for the url

help please.

Comment: how about this? https://regex101.com/r/cKLZuo/3

Comment: The last part seems to work, however i changed it to `(\w|(?<=\\.))` instead since there may be other characters that are escaped. but you also should not use `\w` and `\s` in url. not all characters can be used in a url which is why i specifically added the characters to be used.